# Doubly linked list java method for inserting at the beginning

Tags: java, linked-list

I found this code on the web and I am trying to understand how it works.

```
public void insertFirst( int e )
   {if(isEmpty())
        {
            head = trail = new DNode(e, null, null); //(data, prev, next)
        }
        else {
            head.prev = new DNode(e, null, head);
            head = head.prev;
        }
        
        size++;
}
```

In the first part of the code,

```
if(isEmpty())
            {
                head = trail = new DNode(e, null, null); //(data, prev, next)
            }
```

This means that if the Doubly Linked List is empty, then create the `Node` that connects to `prev` null and `next` null. And then set that as head and trail.

And then the second part of code is,

```
else {
                head.prev = new DNode(e, null, head);
                head = head.prev;
            }
```

I don't really understand how this works in the else statement.

Could you please explain this to me?

Thank you

Comment: Sorry, this is not how Stack Overflow works. This is not a forum or tutorial website. Please visit the [help], take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Oh, I am sorry. I am just new to stackoverflow. Thank you for letting me know.

Answer (score 0):

I'll break it down a little and comment the code to explain it:

```
public void insertFirst(int e){
    if(isEmpty()) {
        // null <-prev-- [newHead(e)] --next-> null
        DNode newHead =  new DNode(e, null, null);

        // list.head --> [newHead(e)] <-- list.trail
        head = newHead;
        trail = newHead;

    } else {
        // null <-prev-- [newHead(e)] --next-> [head(other_e)] . . .
        DNode newHead =  new DNode(e, null, head);

        // [newHead(e)] <-prev-- [head(other_e)] . . .
        head.prev = newHead;

        // list.head --> [newHead(e)] . . .
        head = head.prev; // since 'head.prev' holds 'newHead'
       
        // now you have this:
        // list.head -> [newHead(e)] --next-> [oldHead(other_e)] --next-> (.. maybe others ..) <-- list.trail
        //              [          ] <-prev-- [                ]
    }
    size++;
}
```

Comment: Then, the oldHead will contain elements and newHead will become a dummy node?

Comment: @bdd0 Nope, `newHead` contains `e` the element you're putting in the list. The `list.head` points to `newHead` as the first node and `newHead.next` points to the `oldHead` as the second node, and `oldHead.next` still points to the elements after it, etc.. All the nodes still keep the elements they're holding. I've updated the comments to be more visual

Answer (score 0):

If the list is empty, you just create a single node, which has no `prev` and no `next` elements.

If the list is not empty:

```
null <- [head] -> [node] ...
```

this is a structure of a non-empty head node.
If you insert a new `head` the algorithm is to:

1. `[new_head] <- [head]` *// head.prev = new DNode(e, null, head);*
   in the constructor of DNode `null` means that a `new_head` has no `prev` element.
   and `head` means that the next element of `new_head` is `head`.
2. BUT you haven't changed the `head` reference yet. So, you set a new head reference (= new_head) as `head = head.prev;` because `head.prev == new_head`.

Comment: if the list is empty, then I will create a single node that has no 'prev' and 'next. Does this mean that the node will also be head and tail as well?

Comment: if the list is empty, then I will create a single node that has no 'prev' and 'next. But then, the newly created node will not be connected to the head and tail. I feel like I need to have something to connect the new node to head.setNext(newNode) and tail.setPrev(newNode). Isn't it?

Comment: " Does this mean that the node will also be head and tail as well?" - yes, you are right.  If the list is empty, this means that: `Node head = null` and `Node tail == null`. When you add a new node to the list, you will have `head == tail`. Moreover, this new node won't have any `prev` and `next` elements. `null <- head/tail -> null` (in a single node case).